Is it required that the index set used to position sequences' elements be an ordered set
Can a sequence be defined as a function whose domain is an arbitrary index set? If so, is it required that this set be ordered?

When you write a paper (or a book), you may define sequence however you like.  But do not assume others use the same definition.

Okay, but would it still be called a "sequence"? Is this definition equivalent to the usual definition can one consider the set of integer as the Index set and ignore its ordering or does sequences require the domain to be an ordered set?

By far the most common usage of the word sequence in some set $X$ is as a map $\mathbb N\to X$.
A common generalization used e.g. in topology is that of a net, i.e. a map $I\to X$, where $(I,\leq)$ is a directed set. If you are looking at maps $I\to X$ where $I$ is an arbitrary index set, one usually speaks of a family.

Can one still have the same the properties of sequences when allowing the domain to be any arbitrary index set or are those two definitions not equivalent

@Johngreg Depends on which "properties of sequences" you're talking about.

It is said that ordering of elements in a sequence matters. I don't get what does ordering mean here or if it is possible to define the ordering without an ordered domain

Well in a sequence $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ there is a clear ordering in the sense that one can talk about the first element $a_1$, the second element $a_2$ and so on. With an arbitrary index set (which may even be uncountable) this of course doesn't make sense anymore.

But does that really need an ordered set I mean I could assign to each element of $X$ an element from an arbitrary index set and one would still be able to talk about ordering in some sense. For example , consider this index set {x,y,z,w} can I just assign each element of this index set to some element of the set $X$ and then I would say something like "y" element of $X$

If you want to be able to enumerate all elements of the sequence your index set has to be at most countably infinite. Given a countably infinite set $I$ any bijection $I\to \mathbb N$ can be used to "order" the elements of a sequence indexed by $I$.

@Johngreg Yes, this more or less comes down to choosing a bijection $\lbrace x,y,z,w\rbrace\to \lbrace 1,2,3,4\rbrace$.

Thanks. So I can give a sequence its order without requiring the domain to be an ordered set and thus the usual definition is just a special case of the general definition of the sequence.

Of course you can always speak of the "$i$-th element" of a sequence for $i\in I$. If $f\colon I\to X$, then "$i$-th element of the sequence" is just another name for $f(i)$.

Sorry, but why did you specifically choose this subset for the bijection can I go with something like this $$ { x, y, z, w } \to { 2, 4, 7, 8 } $$

I don't really understand what your actual point or question is. From my point of view, everything relevant has been said. If you have further questions, you might wish to ask a new question.
